# One-to-One Transformation in Bi-variate Probability Density Function

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics, derivatives

I am trying to solve this problem:

"A point is generated at random in the plane according to the following polar
scheme. A radius R is chosen, where the distribution of R2
is χ2 with 2 degrees of
freedom. Independently, an angle θ is chosen, where θ ~ uniform(0, 2π). Find the
joint distribution of X = Rcosθ and Y = Rsinθ."

I am off the final answer by a factor. I thought the transformation from (X,Y) to (R,θ) is not a one-to-one transformation due to the nature of inverse tangent function θ = tan-1(Y/X).  Therefore I need to separate the support and calculate probability density function. Apparently, this is not true. A little bit thought makes me realize that I can identify the angle using X and Y. However, this is not obvious from θ = tan-1(Y/X) which I used to calculate the transformed probability density function. Any argument to reconciles this or clarify it?

Edit: 
I don't think my question is really about deriving Box-Muller but rather to understand the concept of one-to-one transformation. Take a simple example: 
$Y = \sqrt X $ is one-to-one transformation. However, $Y=X^2$ is not a one-to-one transformation.

Take another example:

$$Y_1 = X_1^2 + X_2^2  \quad\text{and} \quad  Y_2 = \frac{X_1}{\sqrt Y_1}$$

is not one-to-to transformation so that when calculate its PDF we need to account the non one-to-one transformation. In solving for PDF of X and Y in the problem above. It is normal to think that:

$$f_{R^2,\theta} = \frac{1}{4\pi}e^{-R^2/2}, \quad 0<t<\inf, \quad 0<\theta<2\pi$$

the transformation is :

$$X = R\cos\theta,\quad Y=R\sin\theta.\quad  $$

The inverse transformation is:
$$R^2=X^2+Y^2,\quad \theta = \tan^{-1}(Y/X)$$

Here comes the question that the inverse transformation given above is not one-to-one in inverse tangent. Do I need to add another contribution to the final probability as in the situation of finding the PDF of $Y$ if $Y=X^2$?

Comment: This is essentially the [_Box-Muller transformation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) used to generate normal random variables from uniform random variables. The angle $\Theta$ is uniform and the squared distance $R^2$ from the origin is $\mathsf{Chisq}(2) \equiv \mathsf{Exp}(rate=1/2),$ which can be generated in terms of a uniform random variable on $(0,1).$ The demonstration is a straightforward change from polar to rectangular coordinates.

Comment: Also perhaps look at [_this Q @ A_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481237/proof-of-box-muller-transform-polar-form) on our site.

Comment: Also see this post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845710/determine-the-joint-distribution-of-a-random-vector-in-re2/.